# Rails 4: How do I display an square thumbnail image using MiniMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick, minimagick

I'd like to display an **square** thumbnail image with using MiniMagick.

The image is not displayed in a square shape although it displays.

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  .
  .
  .
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  .
  .
  .
  storage :file
  .
  .
  .
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  .
  .
  .
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [150, 150]
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

views\aritcles_article.html.erb

```
<li>
    <% article.photos.each do |photo| %>
      <%= image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb).to_s) if photo.image? %>
   <% end %>
</li>
```

views\shared_article_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new article..." %>
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :article_id %>
      <%= p.label :image %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
      <% if p.object.image and p.object.image.file %>
    <%= image_tag p.object.image.url %>
        <p><%= p.object.image.file.filename %></p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

models\photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    validates :image, presence: true
end
```

The message **"The form contains 1 error."** and the following error message appear in 'shared/error_messages' when I submit a jpg file.

> - Photos image Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: mogrify.exe: unable to open image `255,': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643. mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format`255,' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555. mogrify.exe: unable to open image `255,': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643. mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format`255,' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555. mogrify.exe: unable to open image `0.0)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643. mogrify.exe: unable to open module file`C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_0)_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/682. mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `0.0)' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're one function off -> [resize_and_pad](http://www.rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/MiniMagick#resize_and_pad-instance_method):

```
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_and_pad => [150, 150]
  end
```

NOTE: You could add a color to `[150, 150, "#ffffff"]` and by default it's going to be transparent.

Unless you're trying to do some more stuff like [cut thumbnail to fit](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#cut) which `resize_and_pad` does most of for you.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response.   the error appears after using `resize_and_pad` when I submit a image. I updated the error message and shared_article_form.html.erb above.

Comment: **SOLVED** It works when I use `include CarrierWave::RMagick` instead of minimagick. `version :thumb do process :resize_to_fill => [150, 150] end`. Thanks Bryan Clark.